# Redelivery settings not being applied

Tags: optimization, jboss, activemq-classic, messaging, redhat

I'm trying to get the settings for redelivery of messages to work in a RedHat environment that uses JBoss EAP 6.2, A-MQ 5.9 standalone and a resource adapter between. The connection factory used is XaPooledConnectionFactory. The resource adapter is configured in the EAP standalone-full-ha.xml. The redelivery settings are set on the broker url.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="activemq-rar-5.9.0.redhat-610379.rar">
                <module slot="5.9.0.redhat-610379" id="org.apache.activemq"/>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.pool.XaPooledConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/a/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory1">
                        <config-property name="brokerUrl">
                            failover:(tcp://localhost:36616,tcp://localhost:36616)?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0&amp;jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true&amp;jms.UserName=xxxxxxxx&amp;jms.Password=xxxxxxxx&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.useCollisionAvoidance=true&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.collisionAvoidancePercent=50&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.useExponentialBackOff=true&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.initialRedeliveryDelay=2000
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="tmFromJndi">
                            true
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.pool.XaPooledConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/b/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory2">
                        <config-property name="brokerUrl">
                            failover:(tcp://localhost:36616,tcp://localhost:36616)?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0&amp;jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true&amp;jms.UserName=xxxxxxxx&amp;jms.Password=xxxxxxxx&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.useCollisionAvoidance=true&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.collisionAvoidancePercent=50&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.useExponentialBackOff=true&amp;jms.redeliveryPolicy.initialRedeliveryDelay=2000
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="tmFromJndi">
                            true
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

When testing, messages are redelivered instantly with no regard to the initial 2 second delay or exponential backoff.

When setting up a test project, however, I'm able to get the settings to work using an ordinary ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory instead, as follows:

```
<resource-adapter id="activemq-rar-5.9.0.redhat-610379.rar">
                <archive>
                    activemq-rar-5.9.0.redhat-610379.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="Password">
                    xxxxxxxx
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="UserName">
                    xxxxxxxx
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="InitialRedeliveryDelay">
                    2000
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="MaximumRedeliveries">
                    5
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="RedeliveryUseExponentialBackOff">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="RedeliveryBackOffMultiplier">
                    2
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                    tcp://localhost:36616?jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                        <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>false</prefill>
                            <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                        </xa-pool>
                        <recovery>
                            <recover-credential>
                                <user-name>xxxxxxxx</user-name>
                                <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
                            </recover-credential>
                        </recovery>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="HELLOWORLDMDBQueue">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            HELLOWORLDMDBQueue
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" jndi-name="java:/topic/HELLOWORLDMDBTopic" use-java-context="true" pool-name="HELLOWORLDMDBTopic">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            HELLOWORLDMDBTopic
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
```

I'm not setting these settings programmatically anywhere in any of the projects. I need to use the XaPooledConnectionFactory, preferably with a configuration similar to the first if possible, but with redelivery settings that actually get applied. Are there any known issues with the XaPooledConnectionFactory regarding this? Or sending parameters through the amq url in general? Putting the  properties from the test project into my XaPooled project makes no difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the "Passing extra options to the nested URLs." section of http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html, any parameters you want to pass through the `failover:` transport into the underlying transport URIs should be prefixed with `nested.`.  I haven't done this myself, so I can't say for sure that it's right, but it's definitely a place to start.